# React Native App has a problem with some Wifi networks

Tags: react-native, expo

I am experiencing an unusual problem that I'm unsure how to resolve or identify the cause.

While the app functions perfectly in the simulation environment, some users have reported encountering a blank screen after opening it. Specifically, when certain users are connected to Wi-Fi and open the app, they see a blank screen.

To investigate further, I tested the app on my phone using my home Wi-Fi, and it worked fine without any issues. However, when I visited my local gym and connected to their Wi-Fi, the app failed to render. There were no crashes or error messages displayed.

In an attempt to replicate the issue on the simulator, I took my laptop to the gym, but the problem did not occur there. It seems to be limited to physical devices.

Interestingly, when I connect to the gym's network and then use a VPN, the app renders perfectly fine.

I am perplexed by this situation. It appears to be related to some security protocol issue with certain routers. However, I am unsure how to begin troubleshooting this problem. It's worth noting that I am using React Native and have not ejected from Expo, so I don't have access to the iOS or Android folders for more in-depth configuration.
Also all my APIs are Https and been using them on this App for years, I just recently updated the App design and upgraded a bunch of library and react native, so it's hard to tell where the problem is coming!